# UIView subviews not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my subclass of UIView (which I have instantiated in Interface Builder), has a couple buttons as subviews that I add to my view in the initWithCoder method like so:

```
theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [theButton setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-150-10, 289, 150, 21)];
            [theButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
            [theButton setOpaque:YES];
            [theButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:32.0]];
            [theButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [theButton.titleLabel setText:@"text"];
            [self addSubview:theButton];
            [theButton addTarget:myTarget action:@selector(pause) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But the button will not draw as it is supposed to. If I set a breakpoint in `drawRect:`, and `po [self subviews]` with llvm, I get this output.

```
$0 = 0x0c93e860 <__NSArrayM 0xc93e860>(
<UIButton: 0xc93d910; frame = (10 289; 150 21); alpha = 0.5; layer = <CALayer: 0xc93d4a0>>,
<UIButton: 0xc93e2d0; frame = (408 289; 150 21); layer = <CALayer: 0xc93e390>>
)
```

So why isn't my button showing up?

Edit: my superview's recursiveDescription:

```
<UIView: 0xa46b220; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa46b280>>
   | <MyView: 0xa168710; frame = (0 0; 568 320); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1687d0>>
   |    | <UIButton: 0xa16c160; frame = (10 289; 150 21); alpha = 0.5; layer = <CALayer: 0xa16bcc0>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0xa16c3e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa16c480>>
   |    | <UIButton: 0xa16cb00; frame = (408 289; 150 21); layer = <CALayer: 0xa16cbc0>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0xa16c7e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa16c880>>
```

Comment: Assuming theButton and timeButton are the same thing and that is a typo?

Comment: Will the button draw if you put it at 0,0? How big is the UIView and could it be being drawn outside the visible region?

Comment: I doubt it, especially since I can tap on the button just fine, it just doesn't show up.

Comment: go to your root view and do [view recursiveDescription] in debugger, then post it

Comment: Use setAlpha instead of setOpaque and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my guess is that your button is showing up, but you made it a custom button with no text for the normal state (and because you are not using any background image or color, it seems invisible).

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: So this successfully gets the text to draw, but for some reason the text color and text alignment properties that I set to the label arent holding. The font, however, is.

Comment: I figured it out. It took setting *everything* through the button instead of the titleLabel (for text alignment I used the `contentHorizontalAlignment` property).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `setText` on the button's label, try sending `setTitle:forState` to the button (not its title label) instead:

```
[theButton setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Comment: I usually do not include all the states. If the text for a certain state is not defined, it just uses the default one for the UIControlStateNormal, right?

Comment: Well it made the point clear ;). He needs to set the title for the button in the right way. I can't say this hasn't occurred to me once or twice.